# Module structure of base extension via tensor product

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A,B$ be commutative rings.

Defining a product of $B\otimes_{A}B$ as $(b_1 \otimes b_2)\cdot (b_3 \otimes b_4)=(b_1b_3)\otimes(b_2b_4)$, this becomes a commutative ring.

Defining $b\cdot(b_1 \otimes b_2)=(bb_1)\otimes b_2$ for $b,b_1,b_2 \in B$, this becomes a $B$-module.

Then, my textbook says, if I define as $b\cdot(b_1 \otimes b_2)=b_1\otimes (bb_2)$ instead, it defines a different $B$-module structure. I don't understand this.

Isn't the homomorphism defined by $\phi(b_1\otimes b_2)=b_2\otimes b_1$ an  isomorphism of them?

Comment: Why would you need $A, C$ and $M$  here? Which textbook are you talking about please?

Comment: Sorry, I copied as it is in textbook but I really don't need them here. I will edit. The textbook is Japanese one, so I guess you don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be an $A$-algebra and $M$, $N$ be $B$-modules. Here is an example in which $M \otimes_A N$ and $N \otimes_A M$ are isomorphic as $A$-modules, but not as $B$-modules. $\mathbb Z[x]$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module via the inclusion $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Z[x]$. Let $M = \mathbb Z[x]$ be a $\mathbb Z[x]$-module via the identity. Let $N = \mathbb Z[x]$ be a $\mathbb Z[x]$-module via evaluation at $0$. Then $M \otimes_\mathbb Z N \cong N \otimes_\mathbb Z M$ as $\mathbb Z$-modules. However, they aren't isomorphic as $\mathbb Z[x]$-modules, since one is annihilated by $x$ while the other isn't.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is that the notation in the questions seems to suggest that the tensor product just consists of two copies of the same algebra, rather than allowing different module structures on them.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft But then the $B$-modules are isomorphic, no? The OP seems to have omitted some details.

Comment: Yes, precisely, which is why I suspect part of the confusion comes from that. I agree that the questions feels like it is missing some details.

Comment: Dear @Georges, I don't know what to make of the fact that the OP accepted the answer. As discussed in the comments above, seems like there are some details that are missing from the question.

Comment: Dear Ayman, the OP's  acceptance is something I won't discuss. He posted a question that didn't originate with him and I answered *that* question . Needless to say, since I commented on your answer, feel very free to reciprocate on mine :-)

Comment: Dear @Georges, your answer is great, and I see no reason to comment on it. I've just upvoted it. My rationale for posting my answer is that the OP seemed confused about the existence of an isomorphism, so I posted an answer in which no such isomorphism exists. I've edit my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Dear Ayman, your edited answer is a wonderful example (especially the trick of checking annihilators) that I immediately upvoted. (And bravo for your extremely appreciated gentlemanly attitude.)

Answer (score 2):

The ring $B\otimes _A B$ has a canonical $A$-algebra structure and **TWO** different structures of $B$-algebra,  which I'll call $(B\otimes _A B)_l$ and $(B\otimes _A B)_r$, according as multiplication by elements of $B$ happens on the left or on the right.
These $B$-algebra structures are in general different since  if we denote by $\bullet $ and $\circ$ the actions of $B$ on  $(B\otimes _A B)_l$ and $(B\otimes _A B)_r$, we have  $$b\bullet (b_1\otimes b_2)=bb_1\otimes b_2\stackrel {\text{in general}}{\neq} b_1\otimes bb_2=b\circ (b_1\otimes b_2)$$ **However**, as you correctly noticed the swapping morphism of $A$-algebras $$\mu:B\otimes _A B\to B\otimes _A B:b_1\otimes b_2\mapsto b_2\otimes b_1$$ is indeed  **an isomorphism of $B$-algebras** $$\mu:(B\otimes _A B)_l\to (B\otimes _A B)_r$$ as shown by the following trivial calculation : $$\mu(b\bullet (b_1\otimes b_2))=\mu(bb_1\otimes b_2)=b_2\otimes bb_1=b\circ(b_2\otimes b_1)=b\circ\mu(b_1\otimes b_2)$$

**SUMMARY**
The $B$-algebras $(B\otimes _A B)_l$ and $(B\otimes _A B)_r$ are different but isomorphic.